# Is it true $\|a - b\|_1 = \|x_a - y_a \|_1 + \|x_b - y_b\|_1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a$ and $b$ are points in 2d space then is it the case

$\|a - b\|_1 = \|x_a - y_a \|_1 + \|x_b - y_b\|_1$

where $a = (x_a, y_a)$ and $b = (x_b, y_b)$

Note: $\|_1$ means L1 norm

Thanks

Comment: $x_a$ and $y_a$ are real numbers, so $\|x_a - y_a\|_1$ is the $1$-norm in $\mathbb R$, which is just the absolute value, in other words $\|x_a - y_a\|_1 = |x_a - y_a|$, and similarly $\|x_b - y_b\|_1 = |x_b - y_b|$. So the question becomes, is $\|a-b\|_1 = |x_a - y_a| + |x_b - y_b|$?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Let $a = (x_a,y_a) = (1,1)$ and $b = (x_b, y_b) = (0,0)$. Then $a - b = a$.

So $$||a-b||_1 = ||a||_1 = \sum_i |a_i| = |x_a| + |y_a| = 1 + 1 = 2$$

However

$$||x_a - y_a||_1 + ||x_b - y_b||_1 = |x_a - y_a| + |x_b - y_b| = |1-1| + |0-0| = 0$$